# Suggest: Best way to integrate with Microsoft Calendar

Tags: azure, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, icalendar

Requirement: We need MS-calendar to be sync with our app without individual authentication

What we achieved and need : We created Active directory app used to sync with our calendar, but we need push notification or some other web-hook to call our app when our organisation members created any leave events in calendar

We expect the push notification or web-hook for calendar to be without individual authentication.

And also would like to know is there any other way of integration with ICS file for above requirement

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read How to Ask.

Comment: My understanding is that your app is currently using application permissions? What's preventing you from creating subscriptions at this point?

Comment: As of now i m not having licence for the same, if its some assure that it can be done via subscription, i will try to have that licence so only i m waiting for it ,

Can you confirm that, it doesn't need individual authentication to get notification while creating event by user

Answer (score 0):

The [permissions section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) of the documentation shows that the application permission Calendars.Read allows app developers to subscribe to changes in events without requiring the owner of the mailbox to sign-in. This will of course require a tenant administrator's consent. For more information about the different permission types, please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types).

Comment: Can you kindly suggest some other ways to extend the expiration time of subscription, because its allowing us to have maximum time period 3 days

Comment: this should probably be a separate question. Every three days (less an hour before the subscription expires), you can update the subscription to extend the expiration date. This is a way for Microsoft Graph to know that you're still interested in getting notifications for that subscription. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http